# Splitting a PDFTable cell into two columns using Itext Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tabular

I'm trying to draw a table like the one in the image and I can't split a cell into two columns like the last two columns of the table. Please help me with some ideas. I'm using Itext api for creating the PDF file.

[image]

Comment: Thx! I've discovered these things after I've post this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to *split* the **Din care** column, have that data in two columns (so 4 columns in total for the entire table) and then *merge* only the top cell by letting it span two columns. You do this with setting `setColspan(2)` on the **Din care** cell.

Additionally you may want to look at `setRowspan()` for the **Categoria de Varsta** and **Total** cells.